# zsh: command not found: celery

Tags: python, path, celery

Whenever I run `celery -A reminders worker -l INFO --detach`, I get the following error:
`zsh: command not found: celery`
My assumption is that the bug lies in my path variable because that's where these commands are "found".

`$ echo $PATH`

`$ /opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

When I run `pip3 install celery`, I find

```
Requirement already satisfied: celery in /Users/caineardayfio/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (5.1.2)

Requirement already satisfied: click<8.0,>=7.0 in /Users/caineardayfio/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from celery) (7.1.2)

...

Requirement already satisfied: amqp<6.0.0,>=5.0.6 in /Users/caineardayfio/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from kombu<6.0,>=5.1.0->celery) (5.0.9)

Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /Users/caineardayfio/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit->click-repl>=0.1.6->celery) (0.2.5)
```

Does anybody know a solution to this type of error? Thanks!

Comment: Right, you haven’t added your Python binary installation directory to your `PATH`. Add `/Users/caineardayfio/Library/Python/3.8/bin` in your `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try `python3 -m celery -A reminders worker -l INFO --detach –`